# Configure JRebel with Seam 2.2.0.GA (seam-gen project)

Tags: java, jboss, seam, jrebel, seam-gen

I've been trying to configure JRebel 4.5 to work with a project generated by seam-gen. My JBoss server 5.1 is already configured (I can see the JRebel greeting when starting the server, JRebel Agent is enabled), automatic publishing is disabled. I put rebel.xml in src/hot, but it doesn't work, I [tried modifying build.xml to copy rebel.xml to the WAR's WEB-INF/classes and the root of jar](http://zeroturnaround.com/forum/topic.php?id=601#post-2521): I opened the .ear file with Winrar, checked the war and jar, files are in those locations, but still nothing. No class reloading notices in the console, no changes applied on the fly. Clearly I'm missing something. What should I do?

Comment: I would suggest you to contact JRebel support (support@zeroturnaround.com) and send them your jrebel.log (and explain your issue) ;-)